# Would the fast be invalid?

Tags: ghusl, muslim-practices

I have a question, if a woman had a sexual thought and uncontrollably some fluid may have came out because of this (without touching herself) is her fast still valid and would she have to do ghusl?

Answer (score 1):

Pre seminal fluid does not break one's fasting according to the preferred opinion of jurists. If it was a full ejaculation, then it would.